# Wrapping multiple elements in a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I`m trying to wrap two elements in every div with class .fsElement, using two variables for each element. My code looks like this:

```
 $('.lin-stats .fsElement').each(function(){

            var head = $(this).find('h3');
            var parag = $(this).find('p');

  });
```

How can I use the wrapAll() function to wrap those two variables in a single div?

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: I guess you want to use [$.fn.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) not `$.fn.wrapAll()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add them together with the [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function before wrapping them :

```js
var head = $('h3');
var parag = $('p');

head.add(parag).wrapAll('<div id="wrapper"></div>')

console.log($('#wrapper').text());
```

```css
#wrapper{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>Text</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! It`s working!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest is use one `find()` with 2 selectors

```js
$('.outer').each(function(){
  $(this).find('h3, p').wrapAll('<div class="inner">')
})
```

```css
.inner{color:red; border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
 <h3>Heading </h3>
 <p>text</p>
</div>
<div class="outer">
 <h3>Heading </h3>
 <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like OP wants basically to use `$('.outer').wrapInner('<div class="inner">')`   https://jsfiddle.net/Lxw17gjy/

Comment: @A.Wolff possibly..not very clear at all though. Could be other elements in there also or may not even be an outer for all we know

Comment: Ya sure, it's quite unclear what is expected here